# Overflow when unpacking long - Pytorch

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch

I am running the following code

```
import torch
from __future__ import print_function
x = torch.empty(5, 3)
print(x)
```

on an Ubuntu machine in CPU mode, which gives me following error, what would be the reason and how to fix

```
      x = torch.empty(5, 3)
----> print(x)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/tensor.py in __repr__(self)
     55         # characters to replace unicode characters with.
     56         if sys.version_info > (3,):
---> 57             return torch._tensor_str._str(self)
     58         else:
     59             if hasattr(sys.stdout, 'encoding'):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/_tensor_str.py in _str(self)
    216             suffix = ', dtype=' + str(self.dtype) + suffix
    217 
--> 218         fmt, scale, sz = _number_format(self)
    219         if scale != 1:
    220             prefix = prefix + SCALE_FORMAT.format(scale) + ' ' * indent

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/_tensor_str.py in _number_format(tensor, min_sz)
     94     # TODO: use fmod?
     95     for value in tensor:
---> 96         if value != math.ceil(value.item()):
     97             int_mode = False
     98             break

RuntimeError: Overflow when unpacking long
```

Comment: the same for me, but not always, sometimes I get nan entries

Comment: I guess you are following the pytorch tutorial, this error will happen only if you want to print, otherwise it is ok

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since, torch.empty() gives uninitialized memory, so you may or may not get a large value from it. Try

```
x = torch.rand(5, 3)
print(x)
```

this would give the response.